# Link-layer scan in Linux

Tags: networking, linux-networking, network-monitoring

Short version:  How can I determine what IP addresses are present on an Ethernet network without assuming they are all on the same subnet?

Long version:  I've got a device on a network I can SSH into via its ethernet port.  I've got another device which I know is (or should be...) physically connected to the same network switch but which seems to have an invalid IP configuration - I suspect it's getting an autoconfiguration address.  I can use `arp-scan --localnet -I eth0` to see that the device I'm looking for isn't there - presumably because it's not got an IP address on the same subnet.

Is there some way on a Linux box (Debian 8) I can send a message on the Ethernet broadcast address and see what answers, without having to assume it's on the same IP subnet?  I know what the first six digits of the Ethernet MAC are, so I can be reasonably certain whether something that responds is the right thing or not.  Bonus points for some way that will tell me what IP address it has.

Sadly, they're not on the same Ethernet segment, just connected to the same switch, so just listening in promiscuous mode doesn't achieve as much as you might hope.

Comment: Detect Layer2 devices in a network from a position of an end host is almost impossible, since most of them are absolutely transparent to transit traffic, unless you use l2 assistive  protocols like lldp, stp, vtp whatever.

Comment: If you know on which port of the switch it is connected, why can't you mirror this port traffic and look into it?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: All sorts of reasons, not least because it's connected to an unmanaged switch.

Comment: another radical idea: configure a server with 2 ethernet ports as a bridge and plug your device into it and also the switch. you will then be able to see all trafic going through the server...

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't very clear in my question, but the piece of equipment in question is in a locked room on another continent.

Comment: And I broken its network startup script and then rebooted it.